# passing properties field using @value annotation to mocked method is null

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am unable to pass the field by reading from `application-test.properties` file from test to the mocked method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class ReportImplTest {
    @Mock
    private Dependencies dependencies;

    @InjectMocks
    private ReportImplTest  underTest;

   @Test
    public void testgetReports() {
         List<String> reps= underTest.getReports(anyString());
    }

}
```

Here is the actual class of the mocked method

```
@Component
public class ReportImpl {

    @Value("${REP_PROPNAME}")
    String reppropname;

    public List<String> getReports(String rep){

      return staticUtilityclass.process(staticUtilityclass.transform(reppropname,"Reports"));
    }

}
```

reppropname is coming as null in the `getReports` method. Test is executing in test context wheres the `ReportImpl` class will be in application context. Is there a way to get the value of the `reppropname`.
I tried used `@ContextConfiguration (@ContextConfiguration(classes={ApplicaitonBootStarter.class)}`
it is working , but it loads all the beans and dependencies.
Any other way to get the reppropname?

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you used constructor injection instead; you wouldn't need Spring at all for the test.

Comment: @chrylis you mean instead of field injection using value annotation? could you please throw more light

Comment: You can put `@Value` on a method parameter, and Spring is perfectly happy to autowire constructors.

Comment: @chrylis its not working since reppropname is being used in static method.

Comment: Then the class you showed won't compile. (The answer is, of course, "pass it as a parameter".)

Comment: Your test is pretty much useless as it does exactly nothing. It loads the spring configuration and after that ignores is. With a regular Spring application the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` will be `null` as well and your test blows up (the fact that it works makes me wonder if you aren't using Spring Boot). The `ReportImpl` isn't managed by Spring as the `@InjectMocks` creates a new instance, outside of Spring and thus `@Value` won't be processed. So just inject the instance from the application context. Yes it will load everything, but only once and cache everything for subsequent tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the value is not injected here is that you don't provide the configuration to your test class. Spring just doesn't know how to build your bean.
So, as you mentioned you have to annotate the test class with `@ContextConfiguration`. If you don't want to build the entire context with all the beans, you can provide create a test configuration and provide there only the needed beans.

```
@Configuration //can be as well annotated with @TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan("package.to.scan")
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

And now provide this class to your test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class ReportImplTest {
........
}
```

But there is one more thing. Assuming that you have a `@Before` method that performs `MockitAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, you still have your object-under-test declared only with `@InjectMocks`. What does it mean? It means that if you don't initialize this object by yourself, mockito will take care of it and will initialize with using the available constructor, and in this case, spring won't inject the `@Value` annotated field. What you need to do, is to annotate you object-under-test with `@Autowired` so spring will initialize it before mockito will try to take care of it:

```
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private ReportImplTest  underTest;
```